# How to loop through the alphabet when the use has given the starting letter and the number of letters it goes through?

Tags: java

I am stuck on my homework this is it

> Write a program where the user types in a letter and a number, the program will print out the alphabet backwards in order, for the number of characters the user has requested
>   -          C4 = CBAZ
>   -          J1 = J
>   -          Z26 = ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
>   Write a program where the user types in a letter and a number, the program will print out the alphabet backwards in order, for the number of characters the user has requested
>   -          C4 = CBAZ
>   -          J1 = J
>   -          Z26 = ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA

I have managed to do this so far

```
 for (char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++) {
    System.out.println(alphabet);
}
```

However, when I ask the user to select a starting letter and then a number I am unable to use a variable where 'a' is in the code. How would you do this as well as the number part?

This is my attempt:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What letter would you like");
    String x = input.next();
    System.out.println("What number would you like?");
    int z = input.nextInt();
for (char alphabet = x; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++) {
    System.out.println(alphabet);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 10 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `alphabet <= 'z'` did you mean `alphabet <= z` ?

Comment: `alphabet <= x + inputNum?`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to read the letter:

```
char x = input.next().charAt(0);
```